HTML element showing incorrect index when double clicked in Chrome
I have a   list as shown below. I want to double click an item and then get the item index for the double clicked item. I am using Edge / Chrome. It appears to be working in Firefox.
To see the issue, in Edge, run the code snippet and double click an item. The alert shows -1. Now click an item, then double click that same item and the alert shows the index value.


     <select id="jobs" multiple size="15" style=" width: 150px; height: 280px" ondblclick="move('jobright');">
            <option value="1">Day 1 - Sunday</option>
            <option value="2">Day 2 - Monday</option>
            <option value="3">Day 3 - Tuesday</option>
            <option value="4">Day 4 - Wednesday</option>
            <option value="5">Day 5 - Thursday</option>
            <option value="6">Day 6 - Friday</option>
            <option value="7">Day 7 - Saturday</option>
        </select>
     <script>  
    function move(direction)
            {
                var source;
                source = document.getElementById('jobs');
                
        alert(source.selectedIndex);
            }
</script>




Is there a reason you're trying to use a <select> input element for this? It's not what that element is meant for

Can't you provide a minimal, reproducible code as recommended in SO, which you are expected to already know?

I can't reproduce what you say happens--your code snippet works correctly for me in Firefox.

@Sean I don't see an issue with using  for this. It's a standard way to display a list of pre-defined elements from an external source, which is all the asker needs in order to test their JavaScript.

OK then, looks like an Edge / Chrome issue.  It works in Firefox for me as well.  Unfortunately, this needs to run in Edge.

@TylerH It's not standard to try to use it in a context where you need to bind doubleclick events to options. Especially since different user agents render things in vastly different ways. For instance, the accepted answer won't work in iOS safari. Much better to use a list of buttons.

@Sean sure it is, insofar as there is no standard for that; it's a matter of preference. It's an unusual choice, to be sure, but not a wrong one. As for iOS Safari, that is irrevelant; OP is explicitly asking for something to work in Microsoft Edge here. Solutions need not concern themselves with interoperability among browsers.

@TylerH We'll have to agree to disagree.

Interesting enough, the code snippet above began working several days later...hmmmmm

Your problem is that when you double click, first you select an item, then you unselect it, meaning that when the ondblclick event is triggered, you have nothing selected. source.selectedIndex returns -1 because you have just deselected the option. That's why the index is returned correctly when you start with the object selected, because this time the second click selects an item.
You can fix this problem by using the first argument of ondblclick, event. (See: Element: dblclick on MDN). The target property of the event will be the option HTML object, and you can use option.value to get its index. You can still use your direction argument by passing it as the second parameter.


<select id="jobs" multiple size="15" style=" width: 150px; height: 280px" ondblclick="move(event,'jobright');">
  <option value="1">Day 1 - Sunday</option>
  <option value="2">Day 2 - Monday</option>
  <option value="3">Day 3 - Tuesday</option>
  <option value="4">Day 4 - Wednesday</option>
  <option value="5">Day 5 - Thursday</option>
  <option value="6">Day 6 - Friday</option>
  <option value="7">Day 7 - Saturday</option>
</select>
<script>  
  function move(event, direction) {
    alert(event.target.value);
  }
</script>



